# There is this mysterious error in the C compiler

Tags: c

I just don't understand why from time to time I got this error message when compiled a C file:

```
cd "C:\Users\Owner\Desktop\Tubes TBO"
g++ -o main T-08-13509098-mmesinkata1.c T-08-13509098-mesinkata1.c mesinkar1.c: multiple definisi dari `♦'
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\cc21kt92.o:T-08-13509098-mmesinkata1.c:(.bss+0x0): pertama didefinisikan disini: multiple definisi dari `♦'
C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\cc21kt92.o:T-08-13509098-mmesinkata1.c:(.bss+0x20): pertama didefinisikan disini collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm sorry, but my compiler is in Indonesian, so basically the error message above says that there's multiple definition of `♦' in file T-08-13509098-mmesinkata1.c which *is not found* anywhere when I search for that strange symbol in that file....and the compiler doesn't say anything about line where it found that strange symbol.

How can I fix this error?

A week ago I could compile it just fine, but this morning it failed though I didn't change anything in the file since last week...

Comment: Maybe a character encoding problem since you are running an Indonesian compiler? Do you use any special characters at all? Even if it does not necessarily look like that diamond character.

Comment: It wouldn't tell you what line the error is in even if the name was sane. This is a linking error, so it's not associated with any particular place in the code.

Comment: `g++` is not a C compiler, so basically you are compiling a C file as C++. Anything can happen if you do this.

Comment: @Jens It usually works though, and when it doesn't, the error message is a lot more obvious

Comment: @Zack, these are simply two different languages. In particular their idea of when and where symbols are generated differ. They have different `inline` semantics, different ideas what compile time constants are. So yes, the error that the OP encounters can simply come from that.

Comment: @Jens: Please demonstrate.  I don't believe *this specific error* could be caused by compiling C as C++.

Answer (score 4):

For the error occurring while dealing with the *.bss* segment, check your definitions for global variables.

In addition, make sure your code does not contain non-ASCII characters, except in comments.

Comment: More specifically, there *appears* to be an error immediately inside the `.bss` section (0-byte offset), and the second at a 32-byte offset.  (e.g.: Could be 8th `int` declaration, 4th `long long`, etc.)